# Closed form solution for block matrix A in $AXA^T=C$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Looking for help for closed form solution for A, given C and X in the matrix equation

$AXA^T=C$

A (size $M x N$), X ($N x N$) and C ($M x M$) are (appropriately sized) block matrices
$A =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    A_{11} & A_{12} \\
    A_{21} & A_{22} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$, $X = \begin{pmatrix}
    X_{11} & X_{12} \\
    X_{21} & X_{22} \\
    \end{pmatrix}$, $C = \begin{pmatrix}
    C_{11} & C_{12} \\
    C_{21} & C_{22} \\
    \end{pmatrix}$

X and C are covariance matrices (positive semi definite) with $M \leq N$. I am interested in closed form solutions because I need to make some statements about the block matrices that compose A.

Simply multiplying out seems a dead end:

$\begin{pmatrix}
(A_{11}X_{11}+A_{12}X_{21})A^T_{11}+(A_{11}X_{12}+A_{12}X_{22})A^T_{12} &  (A_{11}X_{11}+A_{12}X_{21})A^T_{21}+(A_{11}X_{12}+A_{12}X_{22})A^T_{22} \\ (A_{21}X_{11}+A_{22}X_{21})A^T_{11}+(A_{21}X_{12}+A_{22}X_{22})A^T_{12} & (A_{21}X_{11}+A_{22}X_{21})A^T_{21}+(A_{21}X_{12}+A_{22}X_{22})A^T_{22} \\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
    C_{11} & C_{12} \\
    C_{21} & C_{22} \\
    \end{pmatrix}$

I know that when **solving for X** we can recast the problem as linear regression using the Kronecker product (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), but I don't see how I go from that to a closed form **solution for A**. My other intuition is that this looks a bit like some reduced DARE (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_Riccati_equation), but that's also about solving for X. I'm afraid that's all I have.

I'll also mention that I am mostly (but not only) interested in the special case $C_{12} = C_{21} = C_{11}= 0$. Any help, pointers, things to google are highly appreciated. 
Cheers!

Comment: If $M=N,\,$ then a closed form solution for $\,C = AXA^T\,$ is $$\eqalign{A = A^T &= X^{-1/2}(X^{1/2}CX^{1/2})^{1/2}X^{-1/2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

By Sylvester's law of inertia, the equation is solvable if and only if $\operatorname{rank}(C)\le\operatorname{rank}(X)$. Suppose this is the case. As $X$ and $C$ are positive semidefinite, $X=YY^T$ and $C=DD^T$ for some square matrices $Y$ and $D$. Such $Y$ and $D$ are not unique, but you may pick any choices that you see fit (such as the unique positive semidefinite square roots of $X$ and $C$). The equation can then be rewritten as $(AY)(AY)^T=DD^T$. We now consider the cases $M\ge N$ and $M\le N$ separately.

- When $M\ge N$, we have $\pmatrix{AY&0}=DQ$ and hence $AY=DQ\pmatrix{I_N\\ 0}$ for some orthogonal matrix $Q$. It follows that the general solution is given by
  $$
  A=DQ\pmatrix{Y^+\\ 0} + B(I_N-YY^+),
  $$
  where $B\in M_{M\times N}(\mathbb R)$ is arbitrary and $Q$ is any $M\times M$ orthogonal matrix such that
  $$
  DQ\pmatrix{I_N-Y^+Y\\ 0}=0.
  $$
- When $M\le N$, we have $AY=\pmatrix{D&0}Q$ for some orthogonal matrix $Q$. It follows that the general solution is given by
  $$
  A=\pmatrix{D&0}QY^+ + B(I_N-YY^+),
  $$
  where $B\in M_{M\times N}(\mathbb R)$ is arbitrary and $Q$ is any $N\times N$ orthogonal matrix such that
  $$
  \pmatrix{D&0}Q(I_N-Y^+Y)=0.
  $$

I can't think of anything meaningful to say about the subblocks of $A$. As you can see, the solutions are not unique and any structures or properties of subblocks of $A$ can be easily destroyed by taking a different $Q$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @user1551. Could you clarify what the "+" superscript means here (my lin algebra is rusty, to say the least)? Also my case is M <= N (I edited the question). If we assume that rank(C) <= rank(X) holds, could we impose something else in order to get a unique solution for A? The reason is that uniqueness seems to hold in my use case (I always get the same A) so I'm guessing there is some other aspect that I overlooked.

Comment: @dcneuro $M^+$ means the Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse of $M$. As for uniqueness, what is your use case?

Comment: Thanks. The use case is basically linear regressions (I am actually comparing linear regressions but I leave that out for now). If  A' is a MSE solution for the regression AZ = Y, then taking covariance of both sides we get  $AZZ^TA^T = YY^T$. Using $ZZ^T=X$, $YY^T=C$, we get the original equation. If I know C and X, can't I get A (the means of Y and Z are zero)?

Comment: Sorry I should have used A' throughout

Comment: @dcneuro The main problem is that you cannot get $Y$ or $Z$ back. Note that $ZZ^T=(ZU)(ZU)^T$ for every real orthogonal matrix $U$. So, $Z$ is not uniquely determined by $ZZ^T$ and similarly for $Y$. In other words, once you form the product $ZZ^T$ and throw away your $Z$, information is lost. Since $A$ is derived from $Y$ and $Z$, it is not uniquely determined too. Another problem is that, depending on the size and rank of $Z$, the linear equation $AZ=Y$ itself can have infinitely many solutions.

Comment: I have managed to tweak the problem a bit so that now I have $AXA^T=A′XA′^T$. Under what condition would it be true that A=A′ in this particular case?